# the development of several popular communications protocols to include TCP/ IP -- exact meaning of "include" here?

Tags: comprehension

Source: [The ABCs of IP Addressing by Gilbert Held (2002)](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_ABCs_of_IP_Addressing.html?id=Z4Dc0CpC8mcC&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> Although the TCP/IP protocol suite predated the OSI Reference Model, we
>   can obtain a better appreciation for the functioning of the TCP/IP protocol
>   suite by examining the layering concept associated with communications
>   defined by that model. During the 1970s, approximately a dozen years after
>   the development of several popular communications protocols **to include TCP/
>   IP**, the International Standards Organization (ISO) established a framework for standardizing communications systems. This framework was called the Open
>   System Interconnection (OSI) Reference Model and it defines an architecture
>   in which communications functions are divided into seven distinct layers, with
>   specific functions becoming the responsibility of a particular layer.

I don't think I really understand what is meant by *to include TCP/IP*. It sounds like those several popular communications protocols were specifically developed to include TCP/IP. I don't think that makes a whole lot of sense. *including TCP/IP* (like, there were developed many different network protocols, including TCP/IP) would probably be more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: The phrasing is definitely "not quite right". I don't *exactly* understand the intended sense here, but my guess is the writer should have written something like *...the **upgrading / extension / enhancement** of several popular communications protocols **to include / support** TCP...* Syntactically, all those words work better than ***development*** in this context, but of course there's also the semantic issue.

Comment: In order to include, imho.

Comment: I would prefer ***including*** there instead of ***to include***. Keep in mind that it is the rare tech book that is stylistically above reproach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of

> to include TCP/ IP

is exactly what you think it is, that the popular [communications protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol) were specifically developed to include TCP/IP.  There are other alternatives for handling the transmission layer.

To know this, one must understand that a protocol consists of several layers (low-level to higher levels of abstraction).  The [layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) are hidden from the user and consist of

> application layer
>   transport layer (TCP)
>   internet layer (IP)
>   link layer

The "popular communication protocols" are at the "application layer" level with TCP/IP lower down.

To say

> including TCP/IP

in the context of the sentence would place TCP/IP at the same level as the applications.